# Getting number of elements in array not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

Here I am implementing a simple sort (insertion), but I'm not getting the correct size of the array. Namely, my length variable is getting set equal to 1. Also, what ways could I optimize my code for this insertion sort algorithm? Thanks

```
void insertionSort(int a[])
{
    int sorted = 1;
    int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;
    int tmp;

    printf("%d   ", length);

    if (length < 2)
        return;

    for (i = 1; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        sorted = i;
        while (a[sorted] < a[sorted - 1] && sorted > 0)
        {
            tmp = a[sorted];
            a[sorted] = a[sorted - 1];
            a[sorted - 1] = tmp;
            sorted--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an aversion of passing the array length as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
```

This returns the size of a pointer a,  divided by the size of an int.  Always equal to one.

You will have to pass length to the function, `void insertionSort(int a[], size_t length){`

The function that creates the array has to keep track of the number of elements that are active in the array in order to do this.

Comment: Not necessarily 1: if this is a 64-bit compilation on Unix, the size of the pointer will usually be 8 and the size of the integer will be 4 so the answer will be 2. It won't often be the size of the array, though.

Answer (score 0):

C arrays doesn't really exists. This essentially means that you don't have good abstract support for arrays in C. As an example of this, if I give you (you are the function `insertionSort`)  an array (say `a`) you won't be able to determine it size! Arrays have no size in C.

So what is `sizeof(a)`? First `a` is not an array but a constant pointer to the memory address of the first element; that's all. Then `sizeof(a)` just gives you the size of the pointer `a`.

If you want to manage arrays in C, you must use a variable to store its length. This is why most of functions that deals with arrays have additional parameters `length`.